# Error - The import com.google.android.gms.ads cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, google-play, ads

I follow instruction from Google developpers but i have a problem. I want display publicity ( with AdMob ) and Google Play Game services on my application.

I display publicity with success and it's work ( I use google play services lib ). But when I want to add the BaseGameUtils library to use Google Play Game Services, I have an error.

My import which work previously doesn't works after the new library import.

`The import com.google.android.gms.ads cannot be resolved`

I don't remove google play services lib so why the error appears ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Go to your java build path, under project tab add your lib and then under order & export tab tick your lib, apply settings.
At last just clean the project and lib, it should work properly...

Answer (score 6):

- First solution: Right click error and select the **Fix project setup** like below image.
  [image]
- Select google-play-service.jar right path and click ok

[image]

- Second solution: Delete android-support-v4.jar file under libs folder after restart
  eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of the library in the `build.gradle(:app)` file to

```
"com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0".
```

This did the trick for me

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your library is in your build path.
I had the same problem with another lib.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this error by downloading the latest version (15 as of today) of the Google Play Services.
Then import it again as a library in your project.